# Manually download from github

Tags: cocoapods

Is it possible to download any github project manually?
That is, I do not want to clone the project from repo. Just install project if it exists in directory.
E.g., download here and use:
`/Users/admin/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/EasyPeasy/1.2.1-b39f8` . is it possible to setup suffix?

the question is redirected from [github](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5835)

Answer (score 0):

You can download any project as a zip file and then unzip in your local and use it. Are you looking for any other thing??

Comment: nope. i want to use cocoapods. But `pod install` downloads projects from github. I want to download project beforehand without downloading while `pod install` or `pod update --no-repo-update`